# Comments not threading properly

Tags: comments

I have created a custom page to view a node type "Post" on my website, and I would like to add threaded comments to these posts.

Comments are enabled for this node type, and I've added several Comment Forms to the page (so that you can reply to a specific comment).

When the forms are created, I DPM the Form Render Array, and I can see that the PID for the Comment Entity has been properly set.

However, when I submit this form, the PID for the Form is totally different.

Could this be caused by having more than one form on the page? I've tried to locate where the PID is changed, but it appears that it is changed right as the form is submitted.

Please advise!!!

Comment: @Clive Help! I know you know the answer :D

Comment: Just for your information, '@Clive' won't work on this post, i.e. he will not be notified, since he hasn't commented to this post. You can only notify the previous commenters putting '@' before their names.

Comment: Da***t! I would have used your name, too, but am not going to look up the Alt-Codes necessary to do so. Thanks for the info, I was a little worried about that.